# iPhone PhoneGap restKit / jsonkit duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, cordova, restkit, phonegap-plugins

I was ask to take a existing website make it PhoneGap so all went well I converted it to backbone included phonecap.js for the more funky stuff. Then I was ask to create a AR view so I told the people I will do this in native rather because I am not sure it will be possible in PhoneGap or it will just take to long.

So I created a separate project where I did the AR component tested it and it worked fine. It uses RestKit to download data and then in camerapreview shows little bubbles representing data.

This week my job was to combine them so you click a button in PhoneGap and then it opens the native viewcontroller. Again all went well.  I created the plug-in it calls the function so next step was to copy all the AR logic over and that where all hell broke loose.

I keep on getting duplicate symbols a whole lot of them I spend 6-7 hours trying to solve it but nothing I went thru 100 of websites with different solutions and none worked.

So 3 o'clock I decide f* restkit let me use just jsonkit and do the mapping myself but the same thing happened duplicate symbols and each time it cordova / PhoneGap and then the library.

Am i doing something wrong or is cordova just no good?

Comment: You should really post an excerpt of those linker error messages (like the first 10).

Comment: Will do a little bit later. From memory it duplicate symbol _newBase64decode in cordova/cordova.framework and deriveddata/.../librestkit.a [nsurl_base64] or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Basically my application and the library I used RESTKit/JSONKit used the same library. So to fix you remove the library that's conflicting either from yours or from the library most cases just remove yours. And then reference the libraries library .h file if you removed yours.